# Check if value is equal to int

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to try and check if a value is equal to one,

**variables.php**

```
<?php
  $server = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "xxxx";
  $dbName = "website2";

  $link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password, $dbName);

  $maintenanceMode = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM website_checks WHERE maintenanceMode = '1'");
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  include 'mysql/variables.php';
?>

<?php
  if ($maintenanceMode == '1') {
     echo "hello";
  } else {
     echo mysql_error();
  }
?>
```

I get no error. Please help?

thanks inadvance!

Comment: How do you expect to get errors, if you don't check for them? Also you probably want to count the [num. of rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Comment: Oh. Well I got errors before then I added `$link` to `$maintenanceMode` then I didn't get errors.

Comment: Turn on error reporting and check if your connection fails or your query. And then you will get some errors.

Comment: Okay so, I've checked for num_rows and it returns the integer `1` which I have inserted into my database.

Comment: Your first and main problem is, that you are mixing MYSQL API's, which you can't mix. So you have to decide for an API. (And I would recommend you `PDO` or `mysqli_* prepared statements`; `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed)